# D3: Simple Interaction - Circle with a click

Tags: d3.js, interactive

I am learning D3. I know easy things like making a scatter plot and all. My next step is trying some simple interactive moves. For example, after I have an svg appended, axes and grids made, now I wish to make a circle by clicking a point within the svg canvas. I guess I will have to record coordinate of the clicked point and then append a circle with its cx nad cy, but how? How to record the coordinate?

I appreciate you show me a tutorial, give a hint or best of all an example.

Comment: You probably should think of the action of adding a circle as a data manipulation, rather than a drawing operation. So after a click, you would want to append an element to the array you use for data binding, and then just redraw the entire chart as before.

Comment: Read this: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are familiar with JQuery then D3 should have a friendly feel to it, as it shares a similar API. Specifically in regards to `.on(action, fn)` syntax for attaching an event listener to a DOM selection.

If you check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GordyD/0o71rhug/1/) I have created which implements a very basic implementation of what you are after then you can see this in motion in 21 lines of JS.

```
(function() {
    var svg = d3.select('svg');

    function getRandom(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }

    function drawCircle(x, y, size) {
        console.log('Drawing circle at', x, y, size);
        svg.append("circle")
            .attr('class', 'click-circle')
            .attr("cx", x)
            .attr("cy", y)
            .attr("r", size);
    }

    svg.on('click', function() {
        var coords = d3.mouse(this);
        console.log(coords);
        drawCircle(coords[0], coords[1], getRandom(5,50));
    });
})();
```

The most important aspects of this snippet are on lines 18-20 (`.on(...)` and `d3.mouse(this)`). The `on('click',..)` event is attached to the svg element. When a click occurs `d3.mouse` is called with the current scope as its argument. It then returns an array with x and y coords of the mouse event. This information is then passed to `drawCircle`, along with a random radius to draw a circle on the current SVG canvas.

I advise you to take the jsFiddle and **have a play**!

Comment: Exactly what I wish. It will be a homework for me to draw a line after 2 clicks, for example. :) Thanks!

Comment: Would you please explain the "this" in d3.mouse(this)?

Comment: It's referring to the referent object. So, the svg selector.